# How can I get the transaction history of a bitcoin address?

Tags: transactions, privacy, history, bitcoin-credit-card

Lets say that I have a bitcoin address that is not owned by me. Is it possible to get that address's full transaction history (send/receive addresses and amount), and if the owner bought bit coins using a credit card will I be able to see that and possibly the card number? If not, what can I see with just a random bitcoin address, and who can see that credit card number?

Answer (score 2):

> **Is it possible to get that address's full transaction history (send/receive addresses and amount)**

Yes, all that information is in the public blockchain.

type the address into any [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer)

> **if the owner bought bit coins using a credit card will I be able to see that and possibly the card number**

No. That information is not public. It isn't really part of Bitcoin - not the network protocol, the blockchain or the reference software.

> **who can see that credit card number?**

The merchant involved may, or their payment processor. But this part of your question is absolutely nothing to do with Bitcoin.